# how to set v-btn in bottom left and bottom right vue js vutify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-btn

i am trying to do this but unable to set two button in two bottom corner.
   Following code keeping two buttons side by side.But i need one button in left and other in right.

```
<v-card-actions>
 <v-spacer />
  <v-btn color="primary" v-on:click="gotosignup">SignUp</v-btn>
  <v-btn color="primary" v-on:click="gotohome">Login</v-btn>
</v-card-actions>
```

[image]]

Answer (score 1):

`v-card-actions` are **flexbox**. Just use `ml-auto` on the 2nd btn...

```
    <v-card>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn color="primary">SignUp</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="primary" class="ml-auto">Login</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
```

***OR,*** `justify-space-between` on the container...

```
    <v-card>
        <v-card-actions class="justify-space-between">
            <v-btn color="primary">SignUp</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="primary">Login</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
```

https://codeply.com/p/fhnhCdH1aj

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using [responsive flexbox utilities](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-justify) like:

```
<v-card-actions>
    <v-spacer class="d-flex justify-space-between align-end" />
    <v-btn color="primary">SignUp</v-btn>
    <v-btn color="primary">Login</v-btn>
</v-card-actions>
```

DEMO:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```css
.spacer{height:90vh}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer class="d-flex justify-space-between align-end" />
      <v-btn color="primary">SignUp</v-btn>
      <v-btn color="primary">Login</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-app>
</div>
```